# Why containsKey() of Map only invoke hashCode()?

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

I read interface Map's JavaDoc and it says this:

> Many methods in Collections Framework interfaces are defined in terms of the equals
>   method. For example, the specification for the `containsKey(Object key)` method says: 
>   "returns true if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key `k` such that 
>   `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`." This specification should not be construed 
>   to imply that invoking `Map.containsKey` with a non-`null` argument `key` will 
>   cause `key.equals(k)` to be invoked for any key `k`. Implementations are free to 
>   implement optimizations whereby the `equals` invocation is avoided, 
>   for example, by first comparing the hash codes of the two keys. 
>   (The `Object.hashCode()` specification guarantees that two objects with unequal 
>   hash codes cannot be equal.)

My understanding is when `containsKey()` is invoked, both hashCode() and equals() wil be called, therefore I wrote my own code to test it.

HappyDay class will be stored as a key in HashMap, I override hashCode() and equals() methods, and add `System.out.println("invoking hashCode()" + this.happyHour);` and `System.out.println("invoking equals()");` to check whether the method is invoked or not.

```
public class HappyDay {

    private final int happyHour;

    public HappyDay(int hh) {
        this.happyHour = hh;
    }

    public int getHappyHour() {
        return this.happyHour;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        System.out.println("invoking equals()");
        if (o == null) {return false;}

        if (o == this) {return true;}

        //this is an easy overridden, if happy hour equal, objects will be equal.
        if (o instanceof HappyDay) {
            HappyDay other = (HappyDay) o;
            int otherHappyHour = other.getHappyHour();
            if (this.happyHour == otherHappyHour) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println("invoking hashCode()" + this.happyHour);
        int hash = 7;
        hash = hash + this.happyHour;
        return hash;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<HappyDay,String> hm = new HashMap<>();

        HappyDay hd1 = new HappyDay(1);
        HappyDay hd2 = new HappyDay(2);

        hm.put(hd1, "hd1");
        hm.put(hd2, "hd2");

        if(hm.containsKey(hd2)){
            System.out.println("found");
        }else{
            System.out.println("not exist");
        }
    }
}
```

The Main class is to put two HappyDay instances into HashMap, after insertion(put() method), I invoke `hm.containsKey(hd2)`, as I quoted from JavaDoc, it should call hashCode() first and then call equals(), but the output is

```
invoking hashCode()1 //call put()
invoking hashCode()2 //call put()
invoking hashCode()2 //call containsKey()
found
```

I am expecting there's another output line should be `invoking equals()`, can anyone explain this for me why equals() is not called?

Comment: The passage you quoted says that `equals()` might not be called.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi it means if the key is null the equals() will not be called, it has nothing to do with the containsKey()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hash map first checks key equality via `==`; **only if that fails does it carry on to check with `equals`**.

Now, you put `hd2` into the map as a key, then you are checking `containsKey` using the *same object* as an argument, so the `==` test passes and `equals` is never called.

Checking if a map contains a given key comes down to checking if `getEntry(key)` returns `null`. Let's [look at the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.getEntry%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
360     final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
361         int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
362         for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
363              e != null;
364              e = e.next) {
365             Object k;
366             if (e.hash == hash &&
367                 ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
368                 return e;
369         }
370         return null;
371     }
```

On line 367, we can see that an `==` test is performed *before* a `equals` test. The [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of `||` completely skips the `equals` test if `==` passes, which is what is happening here.

This is probably implemented as it is to skip potentially expensive `equals` methods (e.g. `String#equals` which has to check each character of the given string). The [`equals` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) also states that `o1.equals(o2)` should be true if `o1 == o2`, so this is a valid optimization.

---

Let's do a sanity check by modifying your code slightly:

```
if (hm.containsKey(new HappyDay(2))) {
    System.out.println("found");
} else {
    System.out.println("not exist");
}
```

Now the output is:

```
invoking hashCode()1
invoking hashCode()2
invoking hashCode()2
invoking equals()
found
```

Notice that `equals` is invoked. This makes sense because we are invoking `containsKey` with a *new* but equal object, so the `==` test returns false and the `equals` test is executed.

Comment: I totally agree with you, I dont know why people upvote the wrong answer, but I cannot figure out why. Can you explain more about this, why `==` here?

Comment: @haifzhan Because just like me, they jumped to conclusions, I suppose.

Comment: @haifzhan And `==` is used as a short-circuit, in case `equals()` is expensive to evaluate.

Comment: Oh,it checks whether it is the same object before they are meaningfully equal! Totally make sense now, I should check out the source code, thanks a lot!

Comment: I would think any expensive `equals` method should first check reference equality as a shortcut, but even the virtual method dispatch for `equals` isn't free, so testing before the call is often worthwhile.

Answer (score 5):

[The source code for `HashMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.getEntry%28java.lang.Object%29) tells what's going on.

The `containsKey` method calls `getEntry`:

```
360     final Entry<K,V> More ...getEntry(Object key) {
361         int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
362         for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
363              e != null;
364              e = e.next) {
365             Object k;
366             if (e.hash == hash &&
367                 ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
368                 return e;
369         }
370         return null;
371     }
```

If the hashes match, then the `key`s are compared with `==` first.  Since you pass in the original `hd2` object, the `==` operator returns `true` (it's the same object), and the short-circuiting `||` operator never evaluates the right side, and `equals` isn't called.

If you were to make another `HappyDay`, also passing `2`, then `==` would yield `false` and `equals` would be called.

As for why `==` is there first, I would have to guess that it's on average more efficient to do a fast `==` first, and only fall back on a potentially more costly call to `equals` if they aren't the same object.

Comment: +1 for you. arshajii answered earlier. thank you as well